# Copy Dynamic Range Defined by String Values

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I am trying to figure out how to copy values from a range of cells starting from one text string to another using Office-Scripts.

For example I would like to copy:

```
Name of Owner //Starting String
row 1
row 2
row 3
row n
Total Amount Owed //Ending String
```

And paste these rows in a second sheet.

I believe I can find the first string with something like this:

```
usedRange.find("Name of Owner", {
{ completeMatch: true, matchCase: false, searchDirection: ExcelScript.SearchDirection.forward });
```

But how do I then define the rest of the range in between this string and the ending string (as the specific cell that will contain the ending string will vary)? If someone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Do you know the end string at run time?

Comment: @Skin Hello. Yes! The end string will always be the same string.

Comment: How is your data structured? Do you have multiple owners in the same column? Are they in different columns? Is it just one owner per sheet?

Comment: Howdy @BrianGonzalez Yes, the name of the owners are in the same column. There are several owners on the same sheet with 2 rows in between each entry.

Comment: If you're using Excel tables for each of the owners this would be pretty easy. The owners name would be used as the header and you could add a total row for the table. Once the table had those attributes, you just have to refer to the table using its name and copy its range property. You can learn more about creating Excel tables here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: @BrianGonzalez Thank you for the suggestion! Just letting you know I'm looking into it now.